# Dynamic bootstrap carousel with two items

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a bootstrap carousel (bootstrap 3.2) in which I'm assining the active class to the first element using jquery. The content for the carousel is pulled in dynamically so that's why I'm doing it this way.
This is the code

Html   :

```
<div id="Carousel2" class="carousel slide">
     <div class="carousel-inner" id="test">
       <div class="item active"><p>test1</p></div>
       <div class="item"><p>test2</p></div>
       <div class="item"><p>test3</p></div>
       <div class="item"><p>test4</p></div>
       <div class="item"><p>test5</p></div>
       <div class="item"><p>test6</p></div>
  </div>
     <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel2" class="left carousel-control">&lt;</a>
         <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel2" class="right carousel-control">&gt;</a>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".carousel-inner div:first").addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

And the CSS:

```
.carousel-indicators {
  bottom:20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: -30%;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel-indicators li, .carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #E3E3E4;
    border: 1px solid #B6B7B9;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin:0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -999px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  line-height: 1;
}
ul.thumbnails-carousel img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul.product-images.thumbnails-carousel {
  padding-top: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 749px){
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {

      line-height: 1;
      width: 100%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px){
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    line-height: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.carousel-inner > .active,
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 100%;
}
.product-featured h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
.product-featured .featured-collection {
  margin:80px auto;
}
.product-top-description {
  width:60%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
[data-slide-to] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
a.right.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    right: 0;
}
a.left.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
}
```

This works fine, however I need to display 2 items per row. So at the start test1 and test2 need to show, then on click it goes to test3 and test4 etc.

I can't just put the two elements in one item which is what I'd usually do as I said above the content is pulled in dynamically.

Any ideas how to achieve this in this scenario?